# What does the HTML look like for a jQuery UI Dialog example?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3

I have see many examples of jQuery dialog, but every example has only the Javascript. I am stupid enough to require the HTML.  I understand the jQuery calls and I can get a simple dialog to pop up and go away on mouseover and mouseleave. But my frustration comes in at how I can make this work correctly for a list of items in a Rails 3 view.

For example, I have a simple array of User AR objects that I'm iterating through in a view.  There is too much information on a user to display everything on the screen. Instead, I want to bring that information up in a dialog that displays as the mouse hovers over that user.

I can't find any examples of what the HTML looks like, or a working example of how I can pass the id of the dialog to open.

Plus, as I dynamically create the dialogs on the screen, do I have to put display:none in each one of them? I am really confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the example in a browser that can show you the current DOM (like Firefox with Firebug installed or Chrome).